TypeScript control flow analysis in nested Array maps not working as expected
I am currently using Zod and React Hook Form to build a "generic" form for a project, although I think this issue could be generalized to any mapped object.
The structure of my Zod schema is structured like this:
const mySchema = z.object({
  first_group: z.object({
    a: z.number();
    b: z.string();
  }),
  second_group: z.object({
    c: z.number();
    d: z.string();
  })
});

Every child of a group is an input, and I need to pass the item "path" (e.g.: 'first_group.a') to each input controller for RHF. I am creating the form items with the following array maps:
function MyInput({
  itemSchema
}: {
  itemSchema:  z.ZodNumber | z.ZodString
}) {
  ...
};

// Irrelevant JSX removed for convenience
<...>
  {mySchema.keyof().options.map((group) =>
    // group: "first_group" | "second_group";
    mySchema.shape[group].keyof().options.map((key) => {
      // key: "a" | "b" | "c" | "d";
      return (
        <MyInput
          itemSchema={mySchema.shape[group].shape[key]}
        />
        // TYPE ERROR ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      );
    }),
  )}
</...>

The type error complains about the wrong combinations of group and key that the Zod schema doesn't expect because it's typed exhaustively:
// "first_group", "a"    ✅ VALID
// "first_group", "b"    ✅ VALID
// "first_group", "c"    ❌ INVALID
// "first_group", "d"    ❌ INVALID
// "second_group", "a"   ❌ INVALID
// "second_group", "b"   ❌ INVALID
// "second_group", "c"   ✅ VALID
// "second_group", "d"   ✅ VALID

The issue is that TypeScript can't determine that key: 'a' | 'b' is only possible if group: 'first_group' and viceversa.
Thoughts? Is there any "correct" way to address this issue? I imagine could use some extra group and key variables with type assertion to force the compiler to understand the combinations, but that might not be the best idea.
Thanks!
EDIT:
Ba2sik's could be a way to work around the original type issue, but I was incorrect in missing another parameter for MyInput.
function MyInput({
  id,
  itemSchema,
  ...
}: {
  id:
    | FieldPathByValue<z.infer<typeof mySchema>, number>
    | FieldPathByValue<z.infer<typeof mySchema>, string>;
  itemSchema:  z.ZodNumber | z.ZodString,
}) {
  ...
};

// id: "first_group.a" | "first_group.b" | "second_group.c" | "second_group.d"

// Inside double Array.map
<MyInput
  id={`${group}.${key}`}
  itemSchema={mySchema.shape[group].shape[key]}
/>

Now, even if the itemSchema could be solved by passing it throught directly from the Object.entries iteration, this still leaves my original issue which is the group-key combinations mixed because of the incorrect/incomplete control flow analysis of the original maps.

You can use the type assertion key as keyof z.infer<typeof mySchema.shape[typeof group]>, however that does resolve to never, which doesn't sound very safe

You can iterate its keys using Object.entries, something like this:
return (
  <>
    {Object.entries(mySchema.shape).map(([group, groupSchema]) =>
      Object.entries(groupSchema.shape).map(([key, itemSchema]) => (
        <MyInput
          key={`${group}-${key}`}
          itemSchema={itemSchema}
        />
      )),
    )}
  </>
);


While this works for getting the schemas directly, MyInput also needs to get the item path as ${group}.${key} which is exhaustively typed in it's interface. That's why the title and main issue is regarding the types. This solution makes group and key genetic strings.

I gave a solution that fixed the type error you get. If you want to pass a path also, where's the problem?

I just edited the question with the information I was missing. My point is that while your solution is a way to work around the issue, i don't think it addresses the original issue.

Why do you even need this? Could you also share the code of MyInput?

The id along with the input values is passed on to an external backend which needs the data structured like the zod Schema and expects those specific values.
Regardless of the code, I don't get the harsh questioning.
Although I do appreciate the answer you gave, the question was raised in regards to the TypeScript behaviour in that example, not in other ways of achieving a solution.

I didn't mean to be harsh, I just wanted to know the full picture to try to help you better. If for example you only need this path for the ...register function of react-hook-form, there might be better ways to do so. And btw, are you sure the group-key combinations are mixed? they were fine when I ran this code.

For now I ended up using my original code, passing ${group}.${key} to the input because that id/"path" is used by the external API as is, and getting it from the itemSchema if I were to pass it like you suggested is equally non trivial.
Regarding the "combinations", yes, my TS spits out all combinations of group and key as a union, not only the "real" ones.
